# NSNotificationCenter addobserver not calling the selector method in SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter

I know that this question has been asked quite many times but I am damn tired of searching for this error but couldn't make it.

I have a scenario in which I am moving from one viewController to another i.e (VC1->VC2). I am using NSNotificationCenter to pass some data to the other VC.

**VC1 -**

```
@IBAction func sendNotfctn(sender: AnyObject)
    {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("MY NOTIFICATION", object: self)
         performSegueWithIdentifier("Go", sender: self)//Here I move to VC2. 
    }
```

**VC2**

```
override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "actOnMyNotification:", name: "MY NOTIFICATION", object: nil)

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
func actOnMyNotification(notification:NSNotification)
    {
        print("I recived the notification!")
    }
```

But my selector method is not called. What problem or what error am I making?

**Version used -**  XCode 7.2, SWIFT - 2.1.1

**Update -**

I have VC1 - VC2(embedded in navigation controller). The segue i am using is connected from VC1 to Navigation controller of VC2. So I can't use segue passing for that.

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
    {

```
    if segue.identifier == "Go"
    {
        let destVC = segue.destinationViewController as! VC1//this line is not possible for my above said case
    }
}
```

If any alternatives please suggest.

Comment: This will probably not work as notification will be posted first, and your observer is not set to recieve it.

Comment: This Doen't Calling, Because of Calling PostNotification Before Adding the observer.

Comment: @KiritModi So I can't send any data from VC1 to VC2 using notification.

Comment: @G.Abhisek its Easy Make object in VC2 and Send Data from VC1 to VC2 through segue.

Comment: See More to passing data : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers

Comment: Why you want to send data like this way? you can use `prepareforsegue` to send data or can use delegates and protocol

Comment: let destVC = segue.destinationViewController as! VC2

Comment: @G.Abhisek See my answer to send string from VC1 to VC2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You sent the notification before the second view controller could add itself as observer.

If the goal is to send data to the next ViewController, I suggest using `prepareForSegue`.

You mentioned that your second ViewController is embedded in a `Navigation Controller`. That's ok. You can use something like this:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "YOUR_IDENTIFIER" {

        // The destination ViewController is a NavigationController.
        // The top ViewController of the NavigationController is your target.
        // In this example we are just setting a String in the destination ViewController.
        if let navigationController = segue.destinationViewController as? UINavigationController {

            if let myTargetViewController = navigationController.topViewController as? MyTargetViewController {
                myTargetViewController.myStringVar = "My string value."
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can also be fancy and write the same thing like this:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if let navigationController = segue.destinationViewController as? UINavigationController,
        myTargetViewController = navigationController.topViewController as? MyTargetViewController
        where segue.identifier == "YOUR_IDENTIFIER" {

        myTargetViewController.myStringVar = "My string value."
    }
}
```

[As explained here.](http://nshipster.com/swift-1.2/)

Cheers!

Comment: Suits as to my requirement

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Cheers!

Comment: So if we want can we access other VC's in navigation stack?

Comment: Yes. If you access "navigationController.viewcontrollers", you'll get an Array of ViewControllers. These represent the view controllers currently on the navigation stack.

Answer (score 1):

In you send Object is value send object, but you set **self** value, i think its a error, ok below code its working for me,

VC 1:

```
@IBAction func sendNotfctn(sender: AnyObject)
    {
         NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("PostNotificationName", object: nil)
    }
```

VC 2:

```
override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "actOnMyNotification:", name:"PostNotificationName", object: nil)

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

func actOnMyNotification(notification:NSNotification)
    {

       print("I recived the notification!")
     }
```

hope its helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can send data to second view controller in this way

in first VC

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

if segue.identifier == "Go"
  {
    let destVC = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondViewController // this must be your destintationviewcontroller name
   destVC.name = "hello"
 }
}
```

in secondVC

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
  var name: String?

   override func viewDidLoad()
   {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print(self.name) // prints Hello
 }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In your code you are adding observer in the VC2 viewdidload and it will get called only after you call performsegue.So, till you call perform segue your notification has no observer.
The solution is

```
@IBAction func sendNotfctn(sender: AnyObject)
{
 performSegueWithIdentifier("Go", sender: self)//Here I move to VC2. 
 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("MY NOTIFICATION", object: self)
}
```

in VC1